# ListBox not updating on combobox index change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

My combobox determines what items are shown in the listbox. However the listbox isn't updating when the index is changed.

```
private void cmbProdType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    String query = "Select * From Product Where ProductType = '"+cmbProdType.SelectedValue+"'";    
    Prods = db.GetDataTable(query);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Prods;
    foreach (DataRow dr in Prods.Rows)
    {
        ProdName.Add(dr[1].ToString());
        PrevCount.Add(int.Parse(dr[2].ToString()));                
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = ProdName;
    listBox2.DataSource = PrevCount;       
}
```

The datagridview does update so it rules out the query being at fault.

Comment: Is this windows forms ? or ASP.NET ?

Comment: It's windows forms

Comment: First of all, use parametrized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks. Then it's enought to set `listBox1.DataSource = Prods;` then set `listBox1.DisplayMember` to a field name of product type like `"Name"`. Also if you want to use `SelectedValue` of `listBox1`, then you need to set its `ValueMember` to a filed of `ProductType` like `"Id"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` like

```
listBox1.DataSource = ProdName;
listBox1.DataTextField = "Value";
listBox1.DataValueField = "Key";
```

Also if it's `ASP.NET` then you need to call `DataBind()`

```
listBox1.DataBind();
```